# SELECT from table based on multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql

In mysql, I have a table full of attributes, looking like so:

| USER_ID | ATTR_NAME | ATTR_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Jess |
| 1 | Age | 23 |
| 1 | Sex | m |
| 2 | Name | Jess |
| 2 | Age | 23 |
| 3 | Name | Ann |
| 3 | Sex | f |

(Note that not every attribute must be present for every user)

I want to find all `USER_ID`s where one or multiple attributes do match, for example:

> Show me all users where the name is 'Jess' and the age is '23'.

This should return: `1, 2`

How would I express that in SQL?

EDIT: As people are asking for attempts heres my first try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID 
FROM ATTR_TABLE 
WHERE 
  ( ATTR_NAME = 'Name' AND ATTR_VALUE = 'Jess' ) AND 
  ( ATTR_NAME = 'Age' AND ATTR_VALUE = '23' )
```

This certainly returns nothing, as not a single line has ATTR_NAME `Name` and ATTR_NAME `Age`...

This might be basic SQL, however the learning curve is there and I was not able to come up with a working solution since I am not yet into the SQL jargon and I am not even able to properly google for possible hints.

Comment: While I always like to see an attempt, I hardly think working with an EAV schema'd table to get this output is "basic" and is a far cry from "most basic".

Comment: @JNevill fair enough, but show some attempt, atleast show an attempt that acknowledges that OP knows basic SQL and has made the connection that we need to pivot the attributes out to create the conceptual entity that we can query.

Comment: @sontags, Your attempt helps a bunch. As an option you could consider changing your `() AND ()` to an `() OR ()` since no single record could have both `attr_name='Name'` AND `attr_name='Age'`. Some aggregation will help as well `WHERE (attr_name = 'Name' AND attr_value = 'Jess') OR (attr_name = 'Age' AND attr_value = '23') GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) = 2` The `HAVING` clause here will look for counts that match the number of attributes you are searching for.

Comment: @JNevill This works pretty neatly! Wanna post this as an anwer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table schema is ["EAV" or Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). This is a common schema for applications to use if the number of attributes per entity is unknown or volatile. If this is a schema you own, and the attributes of `user_id` don't change very frequently that it warrants an EAV table, then you may want to consider changing it as the SQL and compute costs can get ugly.

With a normal `user` table, this would be as simple as

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE name='Jess' and Age='23';
```

But with EAV, your attribute columns are stored as values, flipping the relational concept of an RDBMS on its head, to a degree. It's not a "bad" design, it's just that you are trading flexibility for compute/cost.

In your very reasonable requirements, there are a few ways to solve. Likely the most cost effective route is to gather up all records that match your Attribute/Value pairing:

```
(attr_name = 'Name' AND attr_value = 'Jess') 
OR (attr_name = 'Age' AND attr_value = '23')
```

Using an `OR` clause, since no single record in your table can have more than one attribute, and then aggregating and filtering the aggregation with a `HAVING` clause.

Since you are searching for the combination of 2 attributes, `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` will limit your results to only `user_id`s that contain the two attributes you are after.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM mytable
WHERE (attr_name = 'Name' AND attr_value = 'Jess') 
  OR (attr_name = 'Age' AND attr_value = '23') 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/klJnQw-M)

There are other ways to skin this cat, but they often involve pivoting the data through case-expressions or multiple joins and can get very compute heavy as a result. As that wikipedia article states

> The Achilles heel of EAV is the difficulty of working with large
> volumes of EAV data. It is often necessary to transiently or
> permanently inter-convert between columnar and row-or EAV-modeled
> representations of the same data; this can be both error-prone if done
> manually as well as CPU-intensive. [...] The conversion operation is
> called pivoting.

Pivoting gets expensive fast, so any way to limit the need for pivot or multiple table scans is preferred. The method used in this answer is a little risky since it assumes that you won't have more than one `name` or `age` entry for each distinct `user_id`. You can, and should, implement a primary key/constraint to prevent that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The keyword 'Entity-Attribute-Value' helped to find all sorts of resources on the topic!

Comment: "EAV" and "Pivot" are like peas in a pod. I added a bit more to the question at the end to explain. EAV is great for flexibility but if your job is more on the data/analytics side of the company, then the mention of EAV will give you instant heartburn.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a temporary Table

replace `user_attributes` in the first select query, to match your table name

```sql
-- Create a temporary table to store the grouped attributes
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_grouped_attributes AS
SELECT
    USER_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'Name' THEN ATTR_VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'Age' THEN ATTR_VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS Age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'Sex' THEN ATTR_VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS Sex
FROM user_attributes
GROUP BY USER_ID;

-- Now Select / Search your new table
SELECT *
FROM temp_grouped_attributes
WHERE Name = 'Jess' AND Age = 23;
```

the temp_grouped_attributes will be as such

| User ID | Name | Age | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jess | 24 | m |
| 2 | Jess | 23 | Null |
| 3 | Ann | null | f |

The last select query will be as such

| User ID | Name | Age | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Jess | 23 | Null |

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it using self join :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.USER_ID 
FROM ATTR_TABLE a1
INNER JOIN ATTR_TABLE a2 ON a1.USER_ID = a2.USER_ID
WHERE 
  a1.ATTR_NAME = 'Name' AND a1.ATTR_VALUE = 'Jess' 
  AND a2.ATTR_NAME = 'Age' AND a2.ATTR_VALUE = '23';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/itOyMPq0)

Comment: Do you want a solution without using `JOIN` ?

Answer (score -1):

Lets translate your request:

Show me => `SELECT`
all users => `*` or specifically list the fields you want
where  => `WHERE` criteria will follow...
the name is 'Jess' => `ATTR_NAME = 'Name' AND ATTR_VALUE = 'Jess'`
and => `AND`
the age is '23' => `ATTR_NAME = 'Age' AND ATTR_VALUE = '23'`

What complicates this result set is that the entity that you want to select is split across multiple rows, the first step is to transpose the values (being a dynamic schema there are a few options), the following uses self joins for something different:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    userName.USER_ID,
    userName.ATTR_VALUE AS Name,
    userAge.ATTR_VALUE AS Age,
    userSex.ATTR_VALUE AS Sex
FROM user_attributes userName
LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTR_TABLE userAge ON userName.USER_ID = userAge.USER_ID AND userAge.ATTR_NAME = 'Age'
LEFT OUTER ATTR_TABLE userSex ON userName.USER_ID = userSex.USER_ID AND userSex.ATTR_NAME = 'Sex'
WHERE username.ATTR_NAME = 'Name'
) Users
WHERE Name = 'Jess' AND Age = '23'
```

Answer (score -1):

As my understood , you want to get USER_ID of users depends on their attributes of table

```
SELECT t1.USER_ID FROM yourTable t1 JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID WHERE ( t1.ATTR_NAME = 'Name' AND t1.ATTR_VALUE = 'Jess' ) AND ( t2.ATTR_NAME = 'Age' AND t2.ATTR_VALUE = '23' );
```

Comment: Looks like my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77439017/4286884

Answer (score -1):

This is an other way using `group by` and `having` clauses :

```
select USER_ID
from ATTR_TABLE
group by USER_ID
having count(case when ATTR_NAME = 'Name' AND ATTR_VALUE = 'Jess' then 1 end ) = 1
       and count(case when ATTR_NAME = 'Age' AND ATTR_VALUE = '23' then 1 end ) = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fDi6uNFW)

Comment: I have tried this. It works, but appears to be very resource hungry...